# pjax: как отправить несколько запросов подряд?

Tags: javascript, pjax

Из двух pjax-запросов подряд отрабатывает только последний, почему?

```
            var gridId = $(this).data('pjax-grid-id');
            var modalId = $(this).data('pjax-modal-id');
            if (this.id) {
                $.pjax({ //этот запрос не отрабатывает, даже не отправляется
                    url: '/admin/yandex/default/create',
                    container: '#'+this.id,
                    push: false
                });
            }
            if (gridId) { //этот работает
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#'+gridId});
            }
            $('#'+modalId).modal('hide');
```

Если поменять местами, картина та же - отработает последний.

Answer (score 1):

Происходит это потому, что последующий запрос убивает предыдущий:

```
// Cancel the current request if we're already pjaxing
abortXHR(pjax.xhr)
```

Проблему удалось решить таким образом.

`$.pjax` возвращает объект `jQuery deferred`, в котором доступно навешивание обработчика `done()`. Следовательно, можно запустить следующий запрос, когда отработает предыдущий:

```
var gridId  = $(this).data('pjax-grid-id');
var modalId = $(this).data('pjax-modal-id');
if (this.id) {
    var xhr = $.pjax({
        url: '/admin/yandex/default/create',
        container: '#'+this.id,
        push: false
    });
    if (gridId) {
        xhr.done(function() {
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#'+gridId});
        });
    }
}
$('#'+modalId).modal('hide');
```